# Device function throws nopython exception when its returning a list instead of an integer

Tags: python, cuda, numba

a device function I have written always throws a no python exception and I do not understand why or where my error is.

Here a small example that represents my problem.
I have the following device function that I call from a kernel:

```
@cuda.jit (device=True)
def sub_stuff(vec_a, vec_b):
    x0 = vec_a[0] - vec_b[0]
    x1 = vec_a[1] - vec_b[1]
    x2 = vec_a[2] - vec_b[2]
    return [x0, x1, x2]
```

The kernel that calls this function looks like this:

```
@cuda.jit
def kernel_via_polygon(vectors_a, vectors_b, result_array):
    pos = cuda.grid(1)
    if pos < vectors_a.size and pos < result_array.size:
        result_array[pos] = sub_stuff(vectors_a[pos], vectors_b[pos])
```

The three input arrays are the following:

```
vectors_a = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3, 3))
vectors_b = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3, 3))
result = np.zeros_like(vectors_a)
```

When I now call the function via *trace_via_polygon(vectors_a, vectors_b, result)* a no python error is thrown. When the device funtion would return only an integer value, this error is prevented.
Can someone explain to me where my mistake is?

**Edit:** FYI as answered by 
talonmies list construction isn't supported in device code. An alternative that helped me is using tuples, which are supported.

Comment: List construction isn't supported in device code

Comment: Is there another possible way beside writing the subtraction everytime by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your error is that the device function `sub_stuff` is attempting to create a list in GPU code, and that isn't supported.

About the best you can do would be something like this:

```
from numba import jit, guvectorize, int32, int64, float64
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
import math

@cuda.jit (device=True)
def sub_stuff(vec_a, vec_b, result):
    for i in range(vec_a.shape[0]):
        result[i] = vec_a[i] - vec_b[i]

@cuda.jit
def kernel_via_polygon(vectors_a, vectors_b, result_array):
    pos = cuda.grid(1)
    if pos < vectors_a.size and pos < result_array.size:
         sub_stuff(vectors_a[pos], vectors_b[pos], result_array[pos])

vectors_a = 100 + np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3, 3))
vectors_b = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3, 3))
result = np.zeros_like(vectors_a)

kernel_via_polygon[1,10](vectors_a, vectors_b, result)

print(result)
```

which uses a loop to iterate over the individual array slices and perform the subtraction between each element.

Comment: Is there a way to create arrays/lists inside gpu code beside the standard python way?

Comment: @Wikktor There is *no* way to create arrays or lists inside GPU code. It isn't supported

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: An option that worked for me is using tuples. That helped me a lot and is valid vor GPU's